# Timeout problems with Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 Query Web Service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, moss2007enterprisesearch

We are having issues with the MOSS 2007 Web Service. Specifically, the Query/QueryEx method of the API.

We are using the SQL Syntax to query sharepoint, and for most cases, our search execution time is very fast. However, when we add filters and sorts, things start slowing down. In some cases we even get an error.

For example, this MSSQLFT query will give a System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException exception about 50% of the time. The timeout will occur around the 10 seconds mark.

```
SELECT WorkId, Rank, ... , PerforceFolder, PerforceDateSubmitted FROM SCOPE() 
WHERE "scope"='Tech_Depot'  AND (FileExtension = 'cpp' )  
ORDER BY PerforceDateSubmitted, Rank DESC
```

Is there any settings / query parameter / etc... we can use to allow a bigger SEARCH execution time on the sharepoint back-end?

Answer (score 1):

This could have many causes:

- The property used in the search is not indexed, therefore, the search takes longer
- The result set is too big, try specifying a row limit

These tools can help you with development:
- [SharePoint Search Service Tool`](http://sharepointsearchserv.codeplex.com/)
- [SharePoint Search Bench](http://spsearchbench.codeplex.com/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.query.timeout.aspx

Answer (score 0):

believe it or not this 10 second limit is hard coded. The only way round it is to write your own version of the web service. I've done this and the results are here:

http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2009/12/10/search-webservice-for-sharepoint-search-server-with-configurable-timeout/

Hope this helps,

Rupert